# Authentication using Google Service Account in a flask app and deploying on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, postman, service-accounts

Below are my requirements.

- Develop a flask app.
- Use collections in the firebase in the app.
- Deploy this app on Google App Engine using a standard service account

What I have done.

- Created a service account
- Downloaded the corresponding credentials json; I am calling it as key.json
- written a main.py

> ```
> cred = credentials.Certificate('key.json') 
> default_app = initialize_app(cred) 
> db = firestore.client()
>
> user_ref = db.collection_group('Users')
>
> @app.route('/', methods=['GET']) 
> def home():
> return "<h1>Welcome to my first app</h1>"
>
> @app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
> def getUsers():
>     try:
>         result = [user.to_dict() for user in user_ref .stream()]
>         return jsonify(result), 200
>     except Exception as e:
>         result = { "message:"failed"}
>         return jsonify(result), 500
> ```

I have tested this locally and also on deployed on Google App Engine.

In both the cases, key.json was in the same directory as the code.
I have verified that if this key.json is modified to store wrong data, then /users endpoint won't work and gives me a 500 error.

So far so good. I want to know if this is even the right approach.

- I want the key.json authentication to applied even for the root / endpoint.
  i.e., if the user supplies a valid key.json, only then the `Welcome to my first app` should be displayed.
  Else, `Unauthorized user` message needs to be displayed.

Comment: `key.json` is not something that is generally used to authenticate end users.  I think you need to reconsider your authentication scheme.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want to do. It looks like "key.json" is saved in your application's source code. Are you expecting the user to provide the json content? Like @gaefan mentioned, you generally don't use key.json to authenticate users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Gaefan and @DishantMakwana, as well as in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#strategies):

> An API key only identifies the application and doesn't require user authentication. It is sufficient for accessing public data.

So in order to authenticate/authorize your users you should reconsider your strategy. I would recommend you to follow the instructions in the [Authenticating as an end user Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user).

Comment: Since this is very basic authentication they is needed, my manager has agreed for the API key use.

Comment: Also, we are using secret manager to store these api keys.

Comment: I got a pretty good idea on how to use authentication mechanisms. I'll try the oauth also soon.

Comment: ok, as long as you know the limitations and risks involved you can pursue that route, important to note that is quite impractical to provide every user of your app a `key.json`, depending on the number of users and app structure.

Comment: Also, I have found this link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HAbnin3nto
It might be helpful too. I am looking at it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that we can use Google Cloud Endpoints for API management. Works as a charm.